# Is sqlite3.c is compiled with SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT defined in the Windows 3.7.17 distribution?

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-xe3

I switched from using custom Sqlite3 wrapper to System.Sqlite unit from Delphi XE3.

So far I am happy with the outcome but I am not 100% sure if I should still call

```
...
initialization

  sqlite3_initialize;

finalization

  sqlite3_shutdown;
end.
```

in my code?

I guess the real question is

Is sqlite3.c is compiled with SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT defined in the Windows 3.7.17 distribution available for download at http://www.sqlite.org/download.html ?

Comment: I'd think you could comment it out of your code and find out pretty quickly. :-)

Comment: If I comment it - it simply works. But yet I have to be sure. Is there an API call to check the compile time options.

Comment: Execute [`PRAGMA compile_options;`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_compile_options).

Comment: As an alternative, you might consider to [`get FireDAC`](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29318) if you're having Enterprise, Ultimate or Architect edition of Delphi or RAD Studio.

Comment: @TLama Do not forget there are several *free* alternatives around. But FireDac will probably be more supported than the  previous code from "pure" Embarcadero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The official documentation states:](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html)

> SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT
>
> For backwards compatibility with older versions of SQLite that lack
>   the sqlite3_initialize() interface, the sqlite3_initialize() interface
>   is called automatically upon entry to certain key interfaces such as
>   sqlite3_open(), sqlite3_vfs_register(), and sqlite3_mprintf(). The
>   overhead of invoking sqlite3_initialize() automatically in this way
>   may be omitted by building SQLite with the SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT
>   C-preprocessor macro. When built using SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT, SQLite
>   will not automatically initialize itself and the application is
>   required to invoke sqlite3_initialize() directly prior to beginning
>   use of the SQLite library.

Therefore:

- *By default*, this conditional is not defined;
- You can define it if you are *sure* that `sqlite3_initialize()` is called;
- It does not cost anything about performance to run `sqlite3_initialize()` or not, since initialization check will be performed on "upon entry to certain key interfaces", i.e. at opening the DB.

The fact that everything works even if `sqlite3_initialize()` is not called clearly shows it.

In [our *SQLite3* wrapper (allowing static or external linking)](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/02/25/Using-external-MinGW/VisualC-sqlite3.dll-including-benchmark), we enable this conditional, since we explicitly call `sqlite3_initialize()`. But in the official dll, this conditional is not defined.